# Get all files for all .uploadedFiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im looking for a javascript/jquery (doesn't matter which way) to collect all the files i've uploaded.

I have the following code, where .afbeelding is the class for a couple of file input fields

```
var geuploadeAfbeeldingen = $('.afbeeldingen').files;
  for (var i = 0; i < geuploadeAfbeeldingen.length; i++) {
}
```

This somehow doesnt seem to work. When i try `document.getElementsByClassName` it also doesn't work. The funny thing however is, that `document.getElementById` seem to work on one input field

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `$('.afbeeldingen')[0].files` instead

Comment: i get 0 when i try length: `afbeeldingen = $('.afbeeldingen')[0].files` and then `alert(afbeeldingen.length)` return `0`

Comment: What browser? Works for me in Chrome Canary: http://jsfiddle.net/GJW7Y/

Comment: Yes it does, however i need to enter a couple of fields and then click a button. Then i need to collect all the data into one single file list object So the [0] won't apply to this.

Comment: You looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bfV7m/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
var files = [],
    geuploadeAfbeeldingen = $('.afbeeldingen').each(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
            files.push(this.files[i]);
        }
    });
```

You end up with an array (*`files`*) that holds each file you have selected through the input elements..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/GJW7Y/1/

---

If you only want the filenames then change

```
files.push(this.files[i]);
```

with

```
files.push(this.files[i].name);
```

Comment: You sir, saved my day. Thanks alot. Bounty will be rewarded when possible!

Comment: Bounty rewarded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
var geuploadeAfbeeldingen = $('.afbeeldingen');
  for (var i = 0; i < geuploadeAfbeeldingen.length; i++) {
      alert(geuploadeAfbeeldingen[i].files[0].name);
}
```

This may help you.

Edit :

`$('.afbeeldingen').files` is not work and `document.getElementById().files` is worked because first one return JQuery object( array of objects) and second one return DOM object.The jQuery object (created by the `$` method) is a wrapper around a DOM element or a set of DOM elements. The normal properties and methods are not available with JQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each input element and return the `files` property.

Something like this is probably the shortest way, using map to iterate through an array:

```
var geuploadeAfbeeldingen =  $('.afbeeldingen').map(function(k, v) { return v.files[0]; }).get();
```

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yeah, I got muddled up, and didn't test it properly. Fixed now.